# Nested Loop: to be dynamic?

Tags: ruby, learn-ruby-the-hard-way

Ok i'm actually doing this exercise to tackle those nested loop questions. I would say this would be the hardest one for me. I tried my best to be more dynamic instead of static. Can anyone give me tips on how to solve this?

expected output:

```
1
1 2
1 2 4
1 2 4 8
1 2 4 8 16
1 2 4 8 16 32
1 2 4 8 16 32 64
1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128
```

this is my static code:

```
n = 1
for i in 1..8

       for c in 1..n
               case i
                     when 1
                        print "1"
                     when 2
                        print "1 2"
                     when 3
                        print "1 2 4"
                     when 4
                        print "1 2 4 8"
                     when 5
                        print "1 2 4 8 16"
                     when 6
                        print "1 2 4 8 16 32"
                     when 7
                        print "1 2 4 8 16 32 64"
                     when 8
                        print "1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128"
               end
                  print "\n"
       end
end
```

I'm not looking for answer. But i would appreciate that you can guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for x in 0..7
  for y in 0..x
    op = 2**y
    print op, " "
  end
  puts ""
end
```

Prints

```
1 
1 2 
1 2 4 
1 2 4 8 
1 2 4 8 16 
1 2 4 8 16 32 
1 2 4 8 16 32 64 
1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128
```

Comment: Ok i got it. I think i lack of maths calculation to solve this question

Comment: why didn't it print the first row as 0?  2 ** 0 is 0 right?

Comment: Yes, :) 2**0 is 1. I was hoping u would mark mine as correct

Comment: Ok my mistake. Normally you would use for loop to solve this kind of questions?

Comment: Yes, and I used it as it's the most basic stuff. Much more easy to understand as well

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the result of every step and add the new step.

Ruby doesn't work much with for's, there are better methods such as the `.upto` method I use here. The `inject` provides the result variable `out` at which you can add the step calculation. The `" #{2**i} "` is the calculation interpolated as a string with a space after.

```
(0.upto 8).inject("") do |out, i|
  puts out
  out << "#{2**i} "
end
```

Which gives

```
1 
1 2 
1 2 4 
1 2 4 8 
1 2 4 8 16 
1 2 4 8 16 32 
1 2 4 8 16 32 64 
1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128
```

Comment: you learn half of the ruby when you thoroughly understand most of the functions of String, Array, and Hash in ruby

Comment: Noted Thank you very much :)